# Copy an Outlook.AddressList object into a new contact folder (Outlook.Folder)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in, contacts

I have an `Outlook.AddressList` object that contains contacts I want to programmatically copy to a new `Outlook.Folder` object.

I've tried the below but it's not actually saving anything into the folder.

```
string myFolderPath = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder().FolderPath + @"\Contacts\SOME FOLDER NAME"    
for (int i = 0; i < myAddressList.AddressEntries.Count; i++)
    {
         Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry = myAddressList.AddressEntries[i];
         Outlook.ContactItem contact = addrEntry.GetContact();
         contact.SaveAs(myFolderPath, Outlook.OlItemType.olContactItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SaveAs` take an enum of type `OlSaveAsType`, not `OlItemType`.
Call ContactItem.Copy (it will return a new copy of the item), then call Move on that new item.

Comment: Perfect thank you. Do you know if there's a way to more efficiently save a large AddressList object than to loop through its AddressEntry's?

Comment: No, one at a time is the only way.

Comment: Also, your code assumes that the address list is Contacts folder based. This will not be the case with other containers, such as GAL.